# Make a swing thread that show a "Please Wait" JDialog

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

The problem is this:
I've a swing application running, at a certain point a dialog requires to insert username and password and to press "ok". 
I would like that when the user press "ok" the swing application does in this order:

1. Open a "Please wait" JDialog
2. Make some operation(eventually displaying some other JDialog or JOptionPane)
3. When it finishes with the operation close the "please wait" JDialog

This is the code that I wrote in the okButtonActionPerformed():

```
private void okButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    //This class simply extends a JDialog and contains an image and a jlabel (Please wait)
    final WaitDialog waitDialog = new WaitDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), false);    
    waitDialog.setVisible(true);
    ... //Do some operation (eventually show other JDialogs or JOptionPanes)
    waitDialog.dispose()
}
```

This code obviously doesn't works because when I call the waitDialog in the same thread it blocks all till I don't close it. 
So I tried to run it in a different thread:

```
private void okButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    //This class simply extends a JDialog and contains an image and a jlabel (Please wait)
    final WaitDialog waitDialog = new WaitDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), false);    
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            waitDialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    ... //Do some operation (eventually show other JDialogs or JOptionPanes)
    waitDialog.dispose()
}
```

But also this doesn't work because the waitDialog is not displayed immediately but only after that the operation completed their work (when they show a joption pane "You are logged in as...")

I also tried to use invokeAndWait instead of invokeLater but in this case it throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Consider using a SwingWorker to do your background work, and then closing the dialog either in the SwingWorker's `done()` method or (my preference) in a PropertyChangeListener that is added to the SwingWorker.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;    
import javax.swing.*;

public class PleaseWaitEg {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JButton showWaitBtn = new JButton(new ShowWaitAction("Show Wait Dialog"));
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(showWaitBtn);
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

   }
}

class ShowWaitAction extends AbstractAction {
   protected static final long SLEEP_TIME = 3 * 1000;

   public ShowWaitAction(String name) {
      super(name);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      SwingWorker<Void, Void> mySwingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){
         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

            // mimic some long-running process here...
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            return null;
         }
      };

      Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((AbstractButton)evt.getSource());
      final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(win, "Dialog", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

      mySwingWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("state")) {
               if (evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                  dialog.dispose();
               }
            }
         }
      });
      mySwingWorker.execute();

      JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
      progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      panel.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      panel.add(new JLabel("Please wait......."), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      dialog.add(panel);
      dialog.pack();
      dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(win);
      dialog.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Notes:

- A key concept is to set everything up, add the PropertyChangeListener, get the SwingWorker running, all ***before*** displaying the modal dialog, because once the modal dialog is shown, all code flow from the calling code is frozen (as you've found out).
- Why do I prefer the PropertyChangeListener to using the done method (as Elias demonstrates in his decent answer here, which I've up-voted) -- using the listener provides more separation of concerns, looser coupling. This way the SwingWorker has to know nothing of the GUI code that is using it.

Comment: It seems to work, thanks (thanks also to @Elias) :) .
But now there's another small problem. When I close the main application (with dispose() ) the SwingWorker thread continue to run. Have I to close it explicitly? Doesn't it terminate when reach the doInBackground's return statement?

Comment: @user2572526: yes it will close automatically when it finishes. How do you know it is still running?

Comment: I solved, it was not a problem of SwingWorker, it was a mistake with the JDialog initialization. (I kenw that it was still running by the Netbeans profiler).
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What if `execute` ends before `dialog.pack()`? Maybe app may stuck then?

Comment: @VitBernatik: I don't know, but it should be tested. Let me see what I can do on this...

Comment: @Hovercraft... I did test it and it seems that `dispose()` waits until `setVisible(true)` is called therefore it is ok.

Comment: @VitBernatik can you clarify whether `dispose()` is _guaranteed_ to wait until `setVisible(true)` is called, and if so, where this is documented? I can't find anything in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()

Comment: @beldaz: I just test on my software. With some long delays. I can not guarantee it will work in newer versions.

Comment: @VitBernatik Thanks. I see there's a similar example given in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get() using a `PropertyChangeListener `

Answer (score 11):

```
public void okButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    final JDialog loading = new JDialog(parentComponent);
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p1.add(new JLabel("Please wait..."), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    loading.setUndecorated(true);
    loading.getContentPane().add(p1);
    loading.pack();
    loading.setLocationRelativeTo(parentComponent);
    loading.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    loading.setModal(true);

    SwingWorker<String, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<String, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws InterruptedException 
            /** Execute some operation */   
        }
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            loading.dispose();
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
    loading.setVisible(true);
    try {
        worker.get();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation of the above answer

It's an easy and replicable way to do...

```
//This code goes inside your button action   
DialogWait wait = new DialogWait();

SwingWorker<Void, Void> mySwingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        //Here you put your long-running process...

        wait.close();
        return null;
    }
};

mySwingWorker.execute();
wait.makeWait("Test", evt);
//end


//Create this class on your project
class DialogWait {

private JDialog dialog;

public void makeWait(String msg, ActionEvent evt) {

    Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((AbstractButton) evt.getSource());
    dialog = new JDialog(win, msg, Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Please wait......."), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    dialog.add(panel);
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(win);
       dialog.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void close() {
       dialog.dispose();
   }
}
```